# Could Romana come to new Doctor Who TV show?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Day of the Doctor* we learn that Gallifrey has been saved and is in another universe which means other Time Lords can come back. In "The Rise of the Cybermen", The Tenth Doctor (when he and Rose got trapped in Pete's world) said words to the effect that travel between universes...

> used to be easy. When the Time Lords kept their eye on everything, you
>   could hop between realities, home in time for tea. Then they died,
>   took it all with them. The walls of reality closed, the worlds were
>   sealed.

In the comics and audio plays, the Doctor and [Romana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romana_%28Doctor_Who%29) had a falling out when she became Lord President. My question is could Romana come into the Whoniverse and re-team up with The Doctor?

Comment: Unless there has been some official pronouncement on the matter, anything we say here will be speculation.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for this site because it's entirely opinion and speculation. The only possible answer is the trivial, and unhelpful, "anything is possible".

Comment: It’s Doctor Who. Literally anything can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, the answer is 'yes' however we know from various episodes ("Doomsday", "Journey's End" and "The Next Doctor") that the Doctor was vastly over-simplifying the process of travelling between universes. The TARDIS is able to identify and exploit a breakage between universes on at least one occasion but only after the Daleks have used a '[reality bomb](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Reality_bomb)' to substantially weaken the dimensional walls. Under normal circumstances the technology required to travel interdimensionally (a "void ship") is simply beyond even Time Lord science.

It's also worth mentioning that the the ultimate fate of Romana wasn't seen in the show. Her final appearance in the **TV** canon would suggest that she's stuck in "[E-Space](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/E-Space)" and hence unavailable given that the "negative coordinates" make it "nearly impossible" to travel there deliberately.

That said, if we accept the prose stories as canon, then she was **rescued** in "[Blood Harvest](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Harvest)" and is living out her life on Gallifrey. She could well make an appearance if the Doctor (or the Time Lords) find a way to cross universes.

---

Out of universe - As with all 'Who' stories, the answer is that if the writers decide that they want to write her in, they can simply hand-wave any difficulties and claim that she was rescued by wibbly-wobbly-timey-wimey stuff or some kind of temporal accident or even just having her magically appear.

Answer (score 0):

Romana wasn't left on Galifrey. She stayed in E-Space when the Tardis came back into normal space through a CVE. Since almost all the CVEs were closed during the events of Logopolis, it seems unlikely that there is any way she could come back into our universe.

Comment: 'Unlikely' things tend to happen pretty frequently in Doctor Who.

Comment: They did manage to re-open one CVE at the end of Logopolis, so it's possible that was the one connected to the negative universe Romana was in. Also, even though the Monitor talked about "universes" plural when he said "We opened the system by creating voids into other universes", referring to the CVEs, it's possible that more than one CVE might have led to the same negative universe.